# Comparing values entered by user with those stored in database

Tags: java, ms-access

I am making a simple login application in `java` `netbeans`. It is connected to `MS Access` database in which i have stored `usernames` and `passwords`.

Suppose any user wants to login to the system using his or her username and password which is already stored in to the database.

**Question**

How can i validate if the user has entered the correct username/password or not ?

Comment: Is this a question of how to connect to Access using Java, or how to validate user/pwd? If the latter, when the user fills in the info and clicks 'Login' (or whatever), then query the table for that Userid. If not found, tell the user. If it is found, then check the password. You should have some provision for limiting how many attempts a user can make (3 or 5?) and then lock the userid if too many tries.

Comment: its about how to validate user/pwd.

Comment: I found a great deal of solutions by googling>> java validate userid password access database

Comment: Thanks for your effort.